# Why doesn't this unexpand seem to work?

Tags: text-processing, columns

It's my understanding that `unexpand` can replace multiple spaces with tabs.

I have a file, `x.x` with contents

```
1  2   3  4 5
```

and I type `expand x.x` but the output is still

```
1  2   3  4 5
```

and doesn't seem to now have tabs.  What am I missing?

Similarly `expand x.x -t20` still seems to give the same output

Comment: What output do you expect? Tabs and spaces look the same here. Does `-t20` really what you expect? (The `man` lists two applications)

Comment: I also tried `> a_file` and editing the file but wasn't able to discern tabs.  How can I tell if there are tabs?

Comment: Running `od -c` or `hd` will show you the presence or absence of tabs in a file suitable for pasting here.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Is the expected behavior the same as `sed -r 's/ +/\t/g' x.x` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expand`  expands tabs (based on how far appart you specify the tab stops are), and `unexpand` unexpands tabs.

```
$ printf '1\t2\t3\n' | expand -t12 | tr ' ' _
1___________2___________3
```

(expand tabs with tab stops every 12 columns).

```
$ echo 1___________2___________3 | tr _ ' ' | unexpand -t4 | tr '\t' t
1ttt2ttt3
```

(unexpand with tab stops every 4 columns).

If your input doesn't have `TAB` characters, `expand` won't do anything on it.

```
        0         1
        0123456789012
$ echo '1  2   3  4 5' | unexpand -t 3,7,10,12 | tr '\t' t
1t2t3t4 5
```

(it won't replace a single space with a tab)